# STL Function Objects on pointer types

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I read that "library guarantees that less (and other function objects) on pointer types is well defined". It is from C++ Primer 5th edition. And example is:

```
vector <string *> nameTable;
sort(nameTable.begin(), nameTable.end(), less<string *>());
```

But when I try this:

```
string *p1 = new string("abc");
string *p2 = new string("abc");
cout << equal_to<string *>()(p1, p2);
```

It returns 0 which means false. Why?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I read and understand wrong the book. It says:

```
vector<string *> nameTable;
sort(nameTable.begin(), nameTable.end(), [](string *a, string *b) { return a < b; });    // undefined
sort(nameTable.begin(), nameTable.end(), less<string*>());    // ok. however, meaningless
```

Comment: The pointer differs, even if content compare as equal.

Comment: You can use `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), less<string*>())` to sort a `vector<string*> v`, but then the order depends on the addresses of the strings and not on their values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparison will compare the *pointers* and not the strings they point to. Comparing pointers using `<` or `>` is specified as *implementation specific*. Using `==` and `!=` are the only well-defined operations on pointers, but it still only compares the pointers.

The [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (as well as [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) etc.) templates *do* have well-specified meanings for comparison of pointers (through specializations). But they still compare the *pointers* and not what they point to.

The simple solution? ***Don't*** use pointers!

In modern C++ there are few uses of pointers beyond polymorphism. Pointers to strings are even fewer (if any) uses for. The exception might be the smart pointers from C++11, but then I recommend you see them in terms of *ownership* rather than self-deleting pointers.

Comment: Maybe edit your post to say **raw** pointers?  Smart pointers have a lot of uses in modern C++

Answer (score 1):

If I say `*p1 = "def";`, does that change `*p2` ? If the two pointers `p1` and `p2` would be equal, it would mean they refer to the same string *object*. And if you change that single string object, then yes, `*p2` would also change. But you have called `new` twice. You have two pointers to two string objects. Changing one doesn't affect the other.

`std::equal<std::string*>`  tells you whether two string pointers are equal, i.e. refer to the same object. `std::less<std::string*>` is a somewhat arbitrary order: if and only if you have two unequal strings pointers, one is less than the other.

(It's "somewhat arbitrary" because the order is well-defined for two pointers into a single string *array*. The pointer to the string with the lowest index will be less than the pointer to the string with the highest index)